# lightning error: [cannot read property 'style' of null]

Tags: lightning

So, i was trying to fetch all accounts and display them in next table based on selection. Each selected Account record will have a 'New Contact' button next to it, and user can add a contact and should get associated with the account where he has navigated from. I used two components for Accounts and another one for new Contact popup. But, button click gives me an error as shown in the attachment. Here is two lines of code i have added in first component that was expected to communicate with second component to bring the popup. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
showModal : function(cmp, ev) {
        document.getElementById("backGroundSectionId").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("newContactSectionId").style.display = "block";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementById` this returning null

Comment: If it's returning `null` then make sure that the elements exist with the Ids you are using in the method(`document.getElementById('Id goes here')`).

Comment: I have made sure that IDs were referred correctly. I took a different approach as below for now but will try with two different components again after going through documentation thoroughly. http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/15/modal-box-lightning-component-salesforce/